# How to Parse XML having multiple Default Namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, nsxmlparser, xml-parsing

Here is my XML Response:

```
 <DIDL-Lite
xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/" 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/"
<item id="1182" parentID="40" restricted="1">
<title>Hot Issue</title>
</item>
</DIDL-Lite>
```

When I am trying to parse it using xELemnt and try assigning to a var like below:

```
   var vnyData = from xmyResponse in xResponse.Descendants("DIDL-Lite").Elements("item")
select new myClass
                                     {strTitle = ((string)xmyResponse .Element("title")).Trim()};
```

This is not yeilding any results.

Thanks,
Subhendu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is a default namespace in the document, you must parse it as if it were a named namespace. For example.

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/";

var xDIDL = xResponse.Element(ns + "DIDL-Lite");
```

Whatever you name the ns variable is unimportant. The key is that anywhere you are passing an element name (XName to be precise) you need to include the namespace + name. You'll note that string is convertible to XNamespace, but you could also use its constructor.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Einstein. In my document there are multiple Namespace.So in that case do I have to write:

XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/";
XNamespace ns1 = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
XNamespace ns2 = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/";
var xDIDL = xResponse.Element(ns + ns1 + ns2 + "DIDL-Lite");

Comment: No, in your XML document any element that does not have a prefix is in the "default" namespace (that is, the one that says xmlns="..." as opposed to xmlns:prefix="...") so you only need to do ns+"ElementName". However, if you were referencing an element in another namespace you'd have to do ns1+"ElementName" or ns2+"ElementName" but never more than one namespace for a particular element name.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your xml schema which should be present in names of the elements you are trying to access. Check out `XNamespace` class.